Icon-only JButtons layering the icon of the most recently clicked JButton when clicked
I'm using java swing components to build up a goofy, very simple RPG java app, and I've run into this weird behavior where when I click on a JButton, it duplicates the icon of JButtons I've pressed previously, along with the title and background of their containing component. Here's my code:
package gameplay;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GameplayUI extends JPanel {
    GameplayManager gpm;
    ImageIcon linedPaper;
    ImageIcon axeIcon;
    ImageIcon daggersIcon;
    ImageIcon swordIcon;
    ImageIcon slimeIcon;
    ImageIcon gremlinIcon;
    ImageIcon ogreIcon;

    JLabel background;

    public GameplayUI(GameplayManager gpm){
        this.gpm = gpm;
        linedPaper = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/linedpaper.jpeg"));
        background = new JLabel(linedPaper);
        axeIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/axeIcon.png"));
        daggersIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/daggersIcon.png"));
        swordIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/swordIcon.png"));
        slimeIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/slimeIcon.png"));
        gremlinIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/gremlinIcon.png"));
        ogreIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/ogreIcon.png"));
        background.setIcon(linedPaper);
        add(background);
        CharacterCreationOverlay();

        System.out.println("daggersIcon status: " + daggersIcon.getImageLoadStatus());
    }

    public void CharacterCreationOverlay(){
        JPanel weaponSelectPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug", "[250][250][250]", ""));
        JLabel instructionLabel = new JLabel("Select a weapon:");
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));

        //Daggers Button
        JButton daggersButton = new JButton(daggersIcon);
        daggersButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(85, 85));
        daggersButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        daggersButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        daggersButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        daggersButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        //Sword Button
        JButton swordButton = new JButton(swordIcon);
        swordButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(79, 120));
        swordButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        swordButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        swordButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        swordButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        //Axe Button
        JButton axeButton = new JButton(axeIcon);
        axeButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(79, 120));
        axeButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        axeButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        axeButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        axeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        //add components to weaponSelectPanel
        weaponSelectPanel.add(instructionLabel, "cell 0 1");
        weaponSelectPanel.add(daggersButton, "cell 0 2, grow");
        weaponSelectPanel.add(swordButton, "cell 1 2, grow");
        weaponSelectPanel.add(axeButton, "cell 2 2, grow");
        weaponSelectPanel.setBounds(75,75, 600, 850);
        weaponSelectPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        background.add(weaponSelectPanel);
    }
}

So the structure of the components is:

GameplayUI which extends JPanel has a JLabel called background.
background is a label and has its icon set to a lined paper ImageIcon.
background has a JPanel called weaponSelectPanel.
weaponSelectPanel has a JLabel called instructionLabel, and three Icon-Only buttons with Icons which have transparency.

At first when I moused over any of the buttons, I was seeing the background, frame title, and instruction JLabels superimposed within the button being rolled over. I then added "setRolloverEnabled(false)" to all three, and that behavior stopped. However, the same behavior still happens when I click on any of the buttons.
It seems like maybe there's something going on with the ChangeListener where when a component is touched, the image of anything I've touched with the mouse gets superimposed over whatever I'm clicking on, as well as whatever I have previously clicked on. I'm not really certain why this is happening or how to resolve it, hoping someone here may have a clue. I tried setting the background color of the buttons to (0,0,0,0), and setting setContentAreaFilled(false) for the JButtons, but I'm not sure what's causing the superimposing of other components.
Minimal Reproducer
I think I've got a fairly simple breakdown of the bug occurring. It's just two classes, a Main which calls a Program, and it requires 3 icons named linedpaper.jpeg, DaggersIcon.png, and SwordIcon.png in the src package, which I will attach below.
Here is the Main class:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
    }
}

And here is the Program class:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Program extends JFrame {
    public Program(){
        //Instantiate Icons
        ImageIcon linedPaper = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/linedpaper.jpeg"));
        ImageIcon daggersIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/DaggersIcon.png"));
        ImageIcon swordIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/SwordIcon.png"));
        ImageIcon axeIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/AxeIcon.png"));

        //Creating outer JFrame
        setTitle("Example Weirdness");
        setSize(750,1000);

        //Creating JLabel for background image, add to JFrame
        JLabel background = new JLabel(linedPaper);
        add(background);

        //Creating components to overlay atop background
        JLabel instructionLabel = new JLabel("Select a weapon: ");

        JButton daggersButton = new JButton(daggersIcon);
        daggersButton.setFocusable(false);
        daggersButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(85, 85));
        daggersButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        daggersButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        daggersButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        JButton swordButton = new JButton(swordIcon);
        swordButton.setFocusable(false);
        swordButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(79, 120));
        swordButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        swordButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        swordButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        //Creating panel to house overlay components, adding components to panel.
        JPanel weaponSelectPanel = new JPanel();
        weaponSelectPanel.add(instructionLabel);
        weaponSelectPanel.add(daggersButton);
        weaponSelectPanel.add(swordButton);
        weaponSelectPanel.setBounds(75, 75, 600, 850);
        weaponSelectPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

        //Add overlay panel to background
        background.add(weaponSelectPanel);

        //set JFrame visible
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

Here are the exact three files I'm using for linedpaper.jpeg - DaggersIcon.png, and SwordIcon.png.
Here is a screenshot of the program at launch:

Here is a screenshot after clicking daggersButton:

Here is a screenshot after clicking swordButton:

Here is a screenshot after clicking daggersButton again:


The Minimal Reproducer runs fine (Java-21), but it won't do anything, there is no action listener ?

You wrote (in your question): It seems like maybe there's something going on with the ChangeListener If you are referring to this ChangeListener, then I could not find such a ChangeListener in the code in your question. What did I miss?

swordButton.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); - don't use background with transparency. Swing doesn't paint the components correctly. In your case you can just use: swordButton.setOpaque(false). See: Backgrounds With Transparency for more information.

Your issue is as @camickr states. Swing does not handle opacity well, and instead you should set the JPanel's opacity to false. Other issues: Take care using a JLabel as a container since it has no layout manager of its own, and really wasn't built to be a container (although, it can be used, if done carefully). Also, when creating [mre] in the future, use publicly available images, such as public static final String SWORD_RESOURCE = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Autorpg-sword.png";, ...

.... then get the image using something like: URL swordURL = new URL(SWORD_RESOURCE); followed by BufferedImage swordImg = ImageIO.read(swordURL);, followed by ImageIcon swordIcon = new ImageIcon(swordImg); if you absolutely need an ImageIcon. This will make it easier for us to test your code without needing to modify it.

Side notes: I would generally avoid extending JFrame unless I plan to change the innate behavior of the JFrame. I also try to avoid calling setSize(...) on anything as it can lead to problems down the road. Better to set preferred size, better still to override getPreferredSize(). Also, if I want to create a button that is just an Icon, I'd use a JLabel instead of a JButton, since it is transparent by default. For labels, I'd use a MouseListener instead of an ActionListener. There are exceptions to this, if I wanted to use AbstractActions, for instance.

@camickr was correct - Switching from setBackground() to setOpaque(false) did the trick. Thank you!
